# Is is possible to inspect the actual XML data before it is encrypted with wsHttpBinding?

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, wshttpbinding

I have created a WCF proxy (with svcutil) that sends data to the server with wsHttpBinding. Is is possible to show the XML before it is encrypted to see the actual data/values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Enable tracing for the service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751526.aspx) and view the logs it creates in the [Service Trace Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx).

ETA: [A handy tutorial.](http://nayyeri.net/tracing-and-message-logging-in-windows-communication-foundation)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to view the request before it's sent. You can use WCF Message Inspectors that can intercept requests just before they are sent and after they are recieved by the server. The same can be done for responses.

Check this very useful article on how to set up [WCF Message Inspectors: Credit Paolo Pialorsi](http://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/archive/2007/08/23/writing-a-wcf-message-inspector.aspx)

MSDN Link - [Message Inspectors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx)

I'd recommend using Message Inspectors if you plan to do anything with the requests/responses, otherwise trace viewer would be better for debugging type checks, as [Langdon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/158502/langdon) suggest.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I had to accept the @Langdon answer as that solved my specific problem.